# Getting exception on removal of a node from the infinispan cluster

Tags: jgroups, infinispan

When i try to remove a node from my infinispan cluster which is using jgroups as transport, I am getting the following exception

```
org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.SuspectException: One or more nodes have left the cluster while replicating command CacheViewControlCommand

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:232)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
at org.infinispan.cacheviews.CacheViewsManagerImpl.clusterPrepareView(CacheViewsManagerImpl.java:299)
at org.infinispan.cacheviews.CacheViewsManagerImpl.clusterInstallView(CacheViewsManagerImpl.java:244)
at org.infinispan.cacheviews.CacheViewsManagerImpl$ViewInstallationTask.call(CacheViewsManagerImpl.java:815)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

and this exception keeps getting printed by all the live nodes for ever.

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using 5.1.0.FINAL, I believe you're seeing this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-1814

The problem is fixed in 5.1.1.FINAL, so the solution would be to upgrade.